# Eclipse. How to delete all calls of a deleted import?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I have to replace the Android standard logging system with a custom one. I deleted `import android.util.Log;` in all the *.java files, and now I have got to delete all the calls, such as `Log.i(MY_TAG, "Something")`, manually. The methods of my logging system have different signatures; so, I cannot simply run "Organize imports" to import my logging class and leave  calls of the standard `Log` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a file search on your workspace, looking for the import log class ("import ...Log"), check the result. Do it again but press the replace button and leave the field empty.

finally change your calls to log.

Comment: I wrote, "Methods of my logging system has **different** signatures, so I **cannot** simply do "Organize imports" to import my logging class and leave the calls of standard Log class"

Comment: I did not stated it clearly, but you will have to change the call to Log to your logging framework manually. Suppressing the import of the android log class will highlight all the calls to replace as compilation error, so you will not miss any call.

Comment: So, the only way to delete all the calls of a method of a class is to delete them manually. I right-clicked being in *.java file, checked a few items (especially Refactor) and did not find anything similar to "Delete all the calls of methods of the class"